# Mongoose encontra mas não atualiza o documento

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Estou usando o mongoose no meu código e não consigo atualizar os documentos, mas com o mongodb ele funciona normalmente, sempre que tento atualizar um documento, ele retorna os seguintes resultados e não atualiza o documento:

```js
{
  n: 1,
  nModified: 0,
  ok: 1
}
```

Meu código de update:

1 ° A função que criei em meu repositório:

```
async update(id: string, entity: object, options: QueryOptions = { upsert: true }): Promise<Query<any, any>> {
   return this.model.updateOne({ _id: id }, entity, options);
}
```

2° Como eu chamo ela:

```
await this.client.database.users?.update(user.id, {
  $inc: {
     xp: wonXP
  }
});
```

Já tentei utilizar `$set` na query de update porém resulta no mesmo

Comment: Tentou usar `findOneAndUpdate` no lugar de `updateOne`?

Comment: Sim, ali na minha função estou utilizando "updateOne", porém adaptei pra um repositório que estou fazendo pra chamar no meu client